# Sharepoint calculated column produces NaN after variable declared as number in Javascript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I currently sum up 8 columns in my sharepoint list in order to get the total value i set this value in the calculated column as number.

Within my Jquery script i declare the variable as a number and then assign the SP list row ID to display the number value, however this dispalys NAN in my table... Can anyone help...

Variable:

```
      Volume_Total[i] = Number($(this).attr("ows_Volume_Total"));
```

Calculated Column Image:[image: Calculated Column Image]

Comment: Not really sure what you're doing but first question would be are you SURE that the problem isn't in the calculated column, does it display the right number?

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).attr("ows_Volume_Total")` is a string. I'm not used to sharepoint, but shouldn't that be an int or something else?

Have you tried to put something like `parseInt($(this).attr("ows_Volume_Total"))` or `parseInt($(this).attr("ows_Volume_Total"))` depending of your need.